# For declaration of the pointer *start, why datatype is not necessary to be written before the variable name in the following code?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct

```
`struct node
{
int num;
struct node *next;
};
*start=NULL;`
```

The pointer *start isn't declared as 'int' datatype but the compiler doesn't show error.

Comment: Probably the code is `struct node
{
int num;
struct node *next;
}
*start=NULL;` ?

Comment: Where's the rest of it?

Comment: Actually the point was that I'd only used pointer types like 'int *ptr' before. This one came to me later on that struct is the datatype written before *start. So what I understood was like 'int:ptr' , similarly 'struct:start' for above situations.